# Using page.getMetrics() to get page load time in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer to measure how fast a set of web sites loads in my environment. My focus is on the quality of network connection and network speed, so I am happy to know the the time taken for a page to *load*, for a layman's definition of load, when all images and html is downloaded by browser.

By using puppeteer I can run the test repeatedly and measure the difference in load times precisely.

I can see that in `64.0.3240.0 (r508693)` `page.getMetrics` and `event: 'metrics'` have landed, which should help me in getting what I am looking for.

But being a newbie in node and js I am not sure how to read the `page.getMetrics` and which of the different key/value pairs give a useful  information in my context.

My current pathetic attempt at reading metrics is as follows:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on('load', () => console.log("Loaded: " + page.url()));
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    const metrics = page.getMetrics();
    console.log(metrics.Documents, metrics.Frames, metrics.JSEventListeners);
    await page.goto('https://yahoo.com');
    await page.goto('https://bing.com');
    await page.goto('https://github.com/login');
    browser.close();
}
run();
```

Any help in getting this code to some thing more respectable is much appreciated :)

Comment: See also [How I can calculate page fully load with Pupppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938315/how-i-can-calculate-page-fully-load-with-pupppeteer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in recent versions you have `page.metrics()` available:

It will return an object with a bunch of numbers including:

- The timestamp when the metrics sample was taken
- Combined durations of all page layouts
- Combined duration of all tasks performed by the browser.

Check out the docs for the [full list](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.metrics.md)

You can use it like this:

```
await page.goto('https://github.com/login');
const gitMetrics = await page.metrics();
console.log(gitMetrics.Timestamp) 
console.log(gitMetrics.TaskDuration)
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Comment: The URL with the description of each metric has moved: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.metrics.md. Thanks for posting this example.