# How can I get the network traffic metrics using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

How can I get the kB transferred (all network traffic) and MB resources, and Finish time in minutes?

[image]

Comment: See also [How I can calculate page fully load with Pupppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938315/how-i-can-calculate-page-fully-load-with-pupppeteer) and [Using page.getMetrics() to get page load time in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077698/using-page-getmetrics-to-get-page-load-time-in-puppeteer)

Comment: await page.tracing.start({screenshots: false}); <Your process>;   const trace = await page.tracing.stop();