# Calculate page load time of page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, lighthouse, web-vitals

I am trying to create a script to calculate total page load time of page, i am using puppeteer and in some scripts i am using lighthouse, i am confused regarding what to follow like should i follow lighthouse method (web.vitals) or should i follow DOM one, and what will be the correct and accurate way to calculate page load time, kindly do suggest

below is the link to the scripts i made for reference

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/104gu0J10tL3Sr3QvaeV8n9uzeRyWQLPS?usp=sharing

i am expecting to create a script to calculate page load time accurately like datadog, site24x7, new relic or dynatrace

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Pleasi include the code directly in the question itself. Links can become invalid etc. Please also explain the difference between the 4 scripts, we shouldn't be obliged to download each file and compare then to detect the differences ourselves

Comment: Please see [How I can calculate page fully load time with Pupppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938315/how-i-can-calculate-page-fully-load-time-with-pupppeteer) and [Using page.getMetrics() to get page load time in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077698/using-page-getmetrics-to-get-page-load-time-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses DOM which might be more efficient than some other library due to a direct timing frame compared to a library loaded into the website to check when the site is loaded.

```
let page_load_time = window.performance.timing.domComplete - window.performance.timing.requestStart;
console.log(page_load_time + "(ms)");
```

Comment: which script is the perfect one? can you tell me the script number you checked?

Comment: @AnshTyagi `let page_load_time = window.performance.timing.domComplete - window.performance.timing.requestStart` if you were to `console.log(page_load_time);` then you would able print out the milliseconds to load the site. I'm not sure what you meant by script number?

Comment: I have shared 4 files

script_01.js
script_02.js
script_03.js
script_04.js

i am asking which one are you referring to?

Comment: @AnshTyagi I am referring to in total, that is how you can calculate page load time. The scripts themselves seem like they are doing more than just that but nonetheless this would be more accurate. This simple one-liner is able to do what each script seems to try to do. Also they seem to follow the same path of operations and I am not able to tell you how to add onto them due to a lack of context and/or illustration on what they do or what they are supposed to do.